# Tabela Anova R para comparar os dados

Tags: r

Eu tenho o seguinte problema: Diferentes porcentagens de algodão (15,20,25,30 e 35%) em uma roupa afim de verificar se quanto maior a quantidade de algodão presente, maior será a resistência da fibra. E os dados são esses:

```
 a=c(7,7,15,11,9)
 b=c(12,17,12,18,18)
 c=c(14,18,18,19,19)
 d=c(19,25,22,19,23)
 e=c(7,10,11,15,11)

i=c(a,b,c,d,e)


m=matrix(i,nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=F)
colnames(m)<-c("15%","20%","25%","30%","35%")
m
      15% 20% 25% 30% 35%
[1,]   7  12  14  19   7
[2,]   7  17  18  25  10
[3,]  15  12  18  22  11
[4,]  11  18  19  19  15
[5,]   9  18  19  23  11
```

> 

Alguem poderia ajudar a montar uma tabela anova para esses dados para verificar se realmente existe diferença se quanto maior a porcentagem de algodão presente, maior sera a resistencia da fibra ?

Comment: Comece com `d <- as.data.frame(m)` e veja a minha resposta a [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235923/tabela-anova-no-r-afim-de-verificar-se-os-dados-s%c3%a3o-significativos). Se, depois, ainda precisar de ajuda diga qualquer coisa.

Comment: É impressão minha ou é o mesmo OP fazendo a mesma pergunta?

Comment: @MarcusNunes Não tinha reparado nisso. Com 9 dias de intervalo...